# How to display categories and end-less sub categories using PHP & MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

**I was wondering what is the best way to display 100's of categories using PHP & MySQL?**

For example, it would not be wise to create a folder for each category or sub category.

**And how would I create my php page to display categories and end-less sub categories?**

**And how would my url look like exactly for example with multiple sub categories?**

```
http://www.example.com/a/b/c/d/e
```

Would it look like something like?

```
http://www.example.com/cat?
```

**How would my database look like?**

Here is how my MySQL databse looks like what should i add or remove?

```
CREATE TABLE categories ( 
id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
parent_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, 
category TEXT NOT NULL, 
url TEXT NOT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY (id), 
INDEX parent (parent_id)
);
```

a good tutorial or a detail example would help out a lot.

Sorry for all the question.

output data.

```
   1. Administrative Support
   2. Arts & Entertainment
         1. Amusement & Theme Parks
         2. Art Appreciation
         3. Artists
               1. A
                     1. a1
                     2. a2
               2. B
               3. C
               4. D
   3. Automotive & Transportation
   4. Network Administration
   5. Server Administration
   6. Web Design
         1. CSS
         2. HTML
```

database storage.

```
id  parent_id   category    url
1   0           Arts &#038; Entertainment   arts-and-entertainment/
2   1           Amusement &#038; Theme Parks    amusement-and-theme-parks/
3   1           Art Appreciation    art-appreciation/
4   1           Artists     artists/
5   4           A   artists/a/
6   4           B   artists/b/
7   4           C   artists/c/
8   4           D   artists/d/
9   0           Automotive &#038; Transportation    automotive-and-transportation/
10  5           a1  artisits/a/a1/
11  5           a2  artisits/a/a2/
12  0           Web Design  web-design/
13  12          HTML    web-design/html/
14  12          CSS     web-design/css/
15  0           Network Administration  network-administration/
16  0           Server Administration   server-administration/
17  0           Administrative Support  administrative-support/
```

Comment: What 'parent_id' and 'category' semantics?
'parent_id' is a reference to 'id'?
'category' stores 'a/b/c/d/e' or only 'e' and 'parent_id' stores identifier of superior category ('id' of 'd'),...?

Comment: @isola009 What 'parent_id' and 'category' semantics are you talking about?

Comment: @isola009 still what are you talking about what are you trying to say?

Comment: @monkeyEYES, I need an example of Categories table data

Comment: @isola009 i hope the added output is what your talking about, dont mind the numbers.

Comment: @monkeyEYE, ok! but these tree how is stored in Categories table? Could you show me table content?

Comment: @isola009 i hope my new edit helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope works:

```
function category_tree( $parent = 0, $parent_url = "www.example.com/" ){
    echo "<ol>";
    $sql = sprintf("SELECT id, category, url FROM categories where parent_id = %d order by category asc", $parent);
    $r = mysql_query( $sql );
    while( $rs = mysql_fetch_assoc( $r ) ){
        $url = $parent_url . $rs['url'];
        $item = sprintf("<li> <a href = '%s' >%s</a> </li>", $url , $rs['category']);
        echo $item;
        category_tree( $rs['id'], $url );
    }
    mysql_free_result( $r );
    echo "</ol>";
}
```