# Get children categories of certain parent. List posts under each category

Tags: php, wordpress

Right now I have this:

```
<?php
    $category = get_category_by_slug( 'collections' );
    wp_list_categories('child_of='.$category->term_id);
?>
```

I want to be able to customize the output but also list the children posts of these categories like this and I also want to customize the layout (each sub category has an image attached to it):

- Parent Category

  - Sub Cat 1

    - Post 1
    - Post 2
  - Sub Cat 2

    - Post 1
    - Post 2

Answer (score 0):

To do this you'd have to loop through each category and then retrieve it's sub categories from the database. A similar question has been answered before:

[How to display categories and end-less sub categories using PHP & MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3484875/how-to-display-categories-and-end-less-sub-categories-using-php-mysql)

Comment: I was hoping there's a way to do that with PHP & wordpress functions. :)